Intersection Observer Not Detecting Collisions in React Breakout Game with TypeScript
I'm working on a Breakout game in React using TypeScript. The game is divided into three main components: WallGrid, Ball, and PlayerSlider. These components are connected using a Game component. I'm using the Intersection Observer API to detect collisions between the ball and the bricks, as well as the ball and the player's paddle.
Here is the code for the WallGrid, Ball, and PlayerSlider components:
WallGrid.tsx:
typescript
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import style from "./style.module.css";

interface Props {
    wallMatrix: number[][];
    observer: IntersectionObserver;
    brickRefs: React.RefObject<React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>[]>;
}

const WallGrid = ({ brickRefs, observer, wallMatrix }: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (brickRefs.current) {
      const refs = wallMatrix.flat().map(() => React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>());
      brickRefs.current.length = 0;
      brickRefs.current.push(...refs);
    }
  }, [wallMatrix]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (observer && brickRefs.current) {
      brickRefs.current.forEach((ref) => {
        if (ref.current) observer.observe(ref.current);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (observer && brickRefs.current) {
        brickRefs.current.forEach((ref) => {
          if (ref.current) observer.unobserve(ref.current);
        });
      }
    };
  }, [brickRefs.current, observer]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full gap-1 h-1/2 grid grid-rows-8 grid-cols-12">
      {wallMatrix.map((matrix, index1) =>
        matrix.map((item, index2) => {
          if (item > 0) {
            const refIndex = index1 * wallMatrix[0].length + index2;
            return (
              <span
                ref={brickRefs.current && brickRefs.current[refIndex]}
                key={`${index1}-${index2}`}
                className={"border-2 border-black rounded-2xl " + style[`brick-${item}`]}
                style={{
                  gridRowStart: index1 + 1,
                  gridRowEnd: index1 + 2,
                  gridColumnStart: index2 + 1,
                  gridColumnEnd: index2 + 2
                }}
              ></span>
            );
          }
          return null;
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WallGrid;

Ball.tsx:
typescript

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface Props {
    ballRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    setObserver: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IntersectionObserver | null>>;
}

const Ball = ({ setObserver, ballRef }: Props) => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 50, y: 100 });
    const [velocity, setVelocity] = useState({ dx: 1, dy: 1 });
    const positionRef = useRef(position);
    const velocityRef = useRef(velocity);

    useEffect(() => {
        positionRef.current = position;
    }, [position]);

    useEffect(() => {
        velocityRef.current = velocity;
    }, [velocity]);

    const changeDirection = (xAxis = false, yAxis = false) => {
        setVelocity((prev) => {
            const newVelocity = {
                dx: xAxis ? -prev.dx : prev.dx,
                dy: yAxis ? -prev.dy : prev.dy
            };
            velocityRef.current = newVelocity;
            return newVelocity;
        });
    };

    const updatePosition = () => {
        setPosition((prev) => {
            const newPosition = {
                x: prev.x + velocityRef.current.dx,
                y: prev.y + velocityRef.current.dy
            };
            positionRef.current = newPosition;
            return newPosition;
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const moveBall = () => {
            updatePosition();
            const { x, y } = positionRef.current;

            if (x <= 0 || x >= window.innerWidth - 40) changeDirection(true, false);
            if (y <= 90 || y >= window.innerHeight - 40) changeDirection(false, true);

            requestAnimationFrame(moveBall);
        };

        const animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(moveBall);
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div
            ref={ballRef}
            className='border-2 border-black bg-red-600 w-10 h-10 rounded-full'
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: `${position.x}px`,
                top: `${position.y}px`,
            }}
        ></div>
    );
};

export default Ball;

PlayerSlider.tsx:
typescript

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useTransformX from '../../hooks/useTransformX';

const PlayerSlider = ({ observer, playerRef }: { observer: IntersectionObserver; playerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> }) => {
    const transform = useTransformX();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (playerRef.current && observer) {
            console.log('Player observer initialized');
            observer.observe(playerRef.current);
        }

        return () => {
            if (playerRef.current && observer) {
                console.log('unobserving');
                observer.unobserve(playerRef.current);
            }
        };
    }, [playerRef.current, observer]);

    return (
        <div
            ref={playerRef}
            style={{
                transform: `translateX(${transform}px)`
            }}
            className={`w-56 h-10 bg-red-600 border-2 border-black rounded-3xl`}
        ></div>
    );
};

export default PlayerSlider;

All these components are connected using the Game component:

Game.tsx:

typescript

import { matrices } from "./../utils/getWallMetrix";
import WallGrid from '../components/WallGrid';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import PlayerSlider from "../components/PlayerSlider";
import Ball from "../components/Ball";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Game = () => {
  let { id = 0 } = useParams();   
  
  const [observer, setObserver] = useState<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);
  const ballRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const brickRefs = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ballRef.current) {
        setObserver(new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    console.log('Collision detected with:', entry.target);
                    // Handle collision
                }
            });
        }, {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: 0.1
        }));
    }
  }, [ballRef.current]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-[10vh] relative flex gap-10">
        <p>High Score: 0</p>
        <p>Score: 0</p>
        <p>Time: 00:00</p>
      </div>
      <div className='w-screen bg-[#2f3542] border-4 border-red-600 flex py-1 flex-col justify-between h-[90vh] '>
        <WallGrid brickRefs={brickRefs} observer={observer} wallMatrix={matrices[+id]} />
        <Ball ballRef={ballRef} setObserver={setObserver} />
        <PlayerSlider playerRef={playerRef} observer={observer} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Game;

The game initializes fine, but I encounter issues with the observer pattern. Specifically, the ball seems to intermittently stop detecting collisions with the bricks and the player paddle. I'm not sure if I'm handling the refs or the observer correctly.

Here are my main questions:

Am I correctly setting up the Intersection Observer for the bricks and the player paddle?
    
Are there any improvements or corrections needed in my use of refs to ensure reliable collision detection?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


Unfortunately I don't think you can use an IntersectionObserver for that. This API is only designed to detect when an element becomes visible via scrolling, not for detecting intersections between absolutely positioned elements.
Instead you can lift all your state up, and write custom logic to detect intersections.
Alternatively, you can store refs of the various divs, use getBoundingClientRect to get their bounds, and use that to determine whether they are intersecting.

Well, that explains it. Thank you so much for the answer. Currently, I am looking for something more optimized, something based on an event-driven paradigm. Does JavaScript provide something like that?

No, there isn't, but even if there was, it wouldn't necessarily be more optimized just because it uses events, as it would still need to compute the intersection at each frame. That said, getBoundingClientRect is probably pretty slow, so I would suggest instead to store the position and size of every element and to compute by hand whether they intersect, it will be as optimized as it can get.
